# Mapping cone of minimal resolutions is not necessarily minimal

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

Let $S=k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ be a standard graded polynomial ring, let $M$ and $N$ be two finitely generated graded $S$-modules and let $f:M\to N$ be a graded map of $S$-modules. Let $\mathbf F$ and $\mathbf G$ be $S$-free graded resolutions of $M$ and $N$, respectively, and let $\varphi:\mathbf F\to\mathbf G$ be a graded lifting of $f$. Then the mapping cone of $\varphi$ is a free graded resolution of $N/f(M)$.

I read that even if the resolutions $\mathbf F$ and $\mathbf G$ are minimal, the mapping cone could be not minimal, but I cannot find an example. Can someone please give me a hint?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try taking $f$ to be an isomorphism.